# How to assign one bone per mesh automatically (e.g. for a robot)

Tags: rigging, rigify

I have a character made with multiple hard surface parts (actually a robot), and a rig (from rigify)

Is it possible to assign each mesh (part) to a bone **automatically** ?
Something like "parent with automatic weight" but assign one mesh 100% to only one bone.

Right now I do it one mesh at a time which is quite long using this process:

1. Select all meshes - parent to the rig with empty group
2. Select one mesh
3. Edit mode
4. Select all vertices (if not all selected yet)
5. Find the correct bone in the vertex groups
6. Click Assign

=> Return to 2.

Comment: there are add-ons called "parent to nearest bone"

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying the add-on but it seems to now work for me, I will see if I can debug it.